# Type conflict in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, oop

We have a project called 'Common'. Another web service project references the project 'Common'. A third project say 'Project A' references project 'Common' and also the web service. 
This creates a type conflict in the 'Project A'. The previous developer manually edited the reference file. 
[image]

The question is how do I re-design this application so that the type conflict gets resolved and also the need for manually editing the reference file. 
FYI, the solution is a C# application.

Comment: I do not think that helps my cause

Comment: Have you done any prior research on this issue?  A quick Google Search for "circular references in .net assemblies" and "circular references in .net assemblies type conflict" yields several promising results.

Comment: @RobertHarvey..I definitely researched the circular reference issue before posting. The simplest solution provided is to break the dependency in one of  the projects. The issue is that web service heavily depends on the Common code and the Project A also does. More than coding, it is a design question. how to make web service reuse the code in Common without causing the type conflict in project A. One solution is to duplicate the common code in the web service and we all know that is bad .

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more information. I can see how **WebServices** project would reference Project.Common, so what is there in **WebServices** that **Project A** needs?  The reason I am asking is you may have to move what you need in **WebServices** to another project.

Comment: @Yogendra - Can you add the code that is in WebServices that is needed in Project A?

Comment: ...The project A is the main entry of the application. The web service makes call to a 3rd party application to get data. The Common project contains shared items like logging, enums, Configurations and so on.

Comment: So what does Project A need from the Web Service (Not at run time but in reference)? Do you need to get data from Project A?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidJS...The end users make a request to the Project A. Project A calls other web services to get data from 3rd party. All this is part of 1 solution,